# Handle static files in production in Django

Tags: python, django, apache, static

I have two directories called `media` and `static`.

When I have `DEBUG = True` everything works but if I change it to `DEBUG = False` the problems arises.

I've read that my server will handle static files in production. I have understood it as

In development it's fine to have all my static files in my directory `static` but when I go in production I need to move all my static files to another directory (it could be `static_www`?) and before starting the server I run `python manage.py collectstatic`. This command will move all the files from `static_www` to `static` and everything works.

But why do I need to have two separate directories with same content? How do the server know that my files 'has been collected' through `collectstatic` (it's just files in a folder so how can it know the difference)? I guess `collectstatic` is primarily used when you have static files in multiple directories and want to collect them all before you go into production.

The variables in my `settings.py` looks like:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_www"),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and it moves from `static_www` to `static` so neither in production nor development my directory `static_www` is not used.

Maybe all these settings are meant for websites which has another server only for handling static files?

Answer (score 0):

`STATIC_ROOT` is where the virtual directory for `STATIC_URL` will point.

Example:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/example.com/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://www.example.com/static/'
```

`collectstatic` will find all static files in `STATICFILES_DIR` and copy to `STATIC_ROOT`.

A request to `http://www.example.com/static/file.jpg` will be handled by Django and `/var/www/example.com/static/file.jpg` will be served.

You can set your static files to be even in another site, using something like:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static.example.com/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'http://static.example.com/static/'
```

In this way, `static.example.com` can be a simple server which will serve files without they be handled by Django, increasing the site performance. Or you can upload to a CDN like Amazon S3 (and CloudFront), etc.

Comment: So I really need two different directories in my project (I know that the directories in STATICFILES_DIR could be outside my project) even though they will end up having the same files?

Comment: They don't need to be different, but can be different. It is interesting in being different so you can ignore the `STATIC_ROOT` in you source control.